# What's the most efficient way to replace some given indices of a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three arrays, `indices`, `values`, and `replace_values`. I have to loop over `indices`, replacing each value in `old_values[indices[i]]` with `new_values[i]`. What's the fastest possible way to do this? It feels like there should be some way to speed it up using NumPy functions or advanced slicing instead of the normal `for` loop.

This code works, but is relatively slow:

```
import numpy as np

# Example indices and values
values = np.zeros([5, 5, 3]).astype(int)

indices = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [1,3]])
replace_values = np.array([[140, 150, 160], [20, 30, 40], [100, 110, 120]])

print("The old values are:")
print(values)

for i in range(len(indices)):
    values[indices[i][0], indices[i][1]] = replace_values[i]

print("The new values are:")
print(values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` to separate `x` and `y` indices, then cast to `tuple` and assign:

```
>>> values[tuple(zip(*indices))] = replace_values
>>> values

array([[[140, 150, 160],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[ 20,  30,  40],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [100, 110, 120],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Where `tuple(zip(*indices))` returns:

```
((0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 3))
```

As your indices is `np.array` itself, you can remove `zip` and use transpose, as pointed out by @MadPhysicist:

```
>>> values[tuple(*indices.T)]
```

Comment: `tuple(zip(*indices))` would be much more effiently written as `tuple(*indices.T)`. That way, you make a tuple from two arrays instead of converting each element into an int object.